# Berry curvature and parallel transport gauge

Tags: quantum-mechanics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

As I understand it, the Berry connection in the parallel transport gauge is null. The Berry curvature however is gauge-invariant and we can compute it in any gauge we wish, including the parallel transport gauge. In this case however, how can the curvature be non-zero? If the parameter space was, say, $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the Berry curvature would be:
\begin{equation}
\Omega(\xi)=\boldsymbol{\nabla}_\xi\times\boldsymbol{A}(\xi)
\end{equation}
And I don't see how this quantity can be non-zero if the connection is null.
I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure it out.